# aws api gateway throws an error Cannot GET /patients

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

we are creating APIs using aws-amplify, the get function throws an error 404 NOT FOUND.

we checked the url in the api gateway console and we found that in the same api one path is working fine while the other one shows `Cannot GET /patients`. this api is retrieving value from dynamoDB table named **patients**. put and post are working but get is having errors.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the stage. A stage is like an environment. you can create stages for e.g development, staging and production environments. Check the api gateway console for the stages deployed.

then you can access:

```
/stage/patients/
/production/patients
```

If you don't see any stages, your api may not have deployed, You can deploy your api to a stage from the console.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the url contains the stage https://20gvids6o9.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/hbs. the data is only retrieved when I specify the partition key in the path and I cannot retrieve all records

Comment: It doesn't return 404 for me. It returns an empty list. I don't follow the issue